# 159/5000 How to protect a sheet in excel if the data from another sheet is copied automatically?

Tags: excel, vba, button, spreadsheet-protection

I'm interested in how to protect a sheet in excel if the data from another sheet is copied automatically and there is a button that should work with the protected copy data?
My my data copy code looks like:

```
Sub CopyRow1()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="pass"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\workbook1.xlsm"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("A5:G5").Copy
    Workbooks("workbook1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048567:G1048567").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'esp
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pass"

End Sub
```

and my code for button is:

```
Sub archive
Dim k, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For k = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, "G").Value = 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, "G").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, "G").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having? You may just need to change `ActiveSheet.Protect` to `Workbooks("Workbook1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect`?

Comment: I did this, but I get error 1004 indicating that I am transferring data to a protected sheet, and when I press debug I am marked with this line in second code: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k,"G").EntireRow.Cut Destination :=Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` and I dont know how to avoid that error.

Answer (score 0):

first open two sheets
one to work and one to link
link one sheet data  to another sheet
now on to link sheet go review tab ,on protect sheet ,ao small window will open , by default 2 ticks will appear , no further more  ticks to be made , enter password say "1" , and on confirm enter 1 close the small window , now  modify data entry sheet , you will see that in link sheet data has too changed ( i have practically checked and found operational )